# React Beginner - starterkits/best practices/tools/tutorials/advices

Tags: react-native

React-Native:

- Any good vagrant or docker environment with all latest tools.
- Beginner level tutorials examples / skelton apps etc.
- Best Practices like folder structure etc.
- Any easy build less time consuming methods.
- Any advices or suggestions for a beginner in React-native.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you have already worked on JavaScript then i dont think you will be having tough time going through react native,but if you are new to java script and app development i would suggest you go through Facebook's React Native official documentation they have started from basics and almost included everything which you will be needing for developing a native Mobile app(Android/iOS).

Here's the link

- [Facebook official documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/)
- [Tutorial's Point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/react_native/index.htm)
- [For iOS](https://www.raywenderlich.com/126063/react-native-tutorial)

Comment: Yeah saw the documentation and tutorials point,but before jumping into how to code, i need to setup up environment using docker or vagrant.Couldn't find any with all latest tools and  not even with an emulator support.

Comment: I haven't worked with Docker and vagant so cant tell you about the set up environment if other than that you need help  then i can help you

Comment: yeah will consult you when i jump into coding.Thnk you.

Answer (score 1):

I found the links from the stackoverflow `react-native` tag description amazingly useful:

- **Getting started**: 
  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
- **Short Videos**:
  https://egghead.io/lessons/react-react-native-up-and-running?series=react-native-fundamentals
- **And probably the most useful one that I found**:
  http://www.reactnativeexpress.com/

I wish I had found the reactnativeexpress site earlier.

Source:
https://stackoverflow.com/tags/react-native/info

**For practice you can start with**:

- https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html
  and transform it into a react-native app.

**For folder structures**:

- you can take a look at one generated with a boilerplate like `Ignite`:
  https://github.com/infinitered/ignite

...And a probably the best paid course: https://www.udemy.com/the-complete-react-native-and-redux-course/

Comment: Yeah very useful links.But still finding it difficult to setup the environment.

Comment: Setting up the environment and the emulator was a challenge for me too.

Answer (score 0):

Providing an update on this issue regarding starter react native templates. Facebook has released create-react-native-app sometime ago and this is one of the best and simplistic starter kits you can use to begin development.

Link - https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app